# How to display either image or video when clicking next or back in pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, video, lightbox

In my gallery, I have thumbnails for images and videos to display in a lightbox. So far I've managed to get the code to work when clicking on any one of the thumbnails; each thumbnail displays the correct type in the lightbox.

The problem occurs when clicking on either the left or right arrow. If it's an image, it'll display. As soon as it lands on a video, a message appears in the middle saying "image could not be loaded." I'm using a magnific.min.js.

Here's the custom code -

$( '.image-popup' ).magnificPopup( {type: 'image' } );

```
$( '.video-popup' ).magnificPopup( {type: 'iframe' } ); 

$('.gallery').each(function() { 
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', 
        type: 'image',
        gallery:{enabled:true}
    });
});
```

What do I need to modify in this code so that the lightbox displays either image or video when the user clicks next or back? (or is the content associated with the next or back buttons controlled elsewhere? :s)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types) for Magnific Popup?

Comment: I did. After a ton of research, I found out that the plugin apparently doesnt support images AND videos. i swapped it with another plugin and it works. I just have to update its style to match everything else.